# Changing arguments of a timer tick event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm coding a .Net application using Windows.Forms in C#. I am making a scoreboard imitation using pictureboxes. The plan is to amount their width 2px every timer tick until they reach desired width. And that's the problem, because I have no idea how to tell the timer tick function what picturebox's width it should increment. I don't want to use a different method for every picturebox, because I don't think it's really the optimal way to do it.

So, the question is, how can I set specified pixtureboxes and desired widths to be affected by timer_tick method?

I am trying to do something like the board in the Polish version of Family Feud: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL-y18ZkbcQ (watch from 3:05)

Comment: What doyou already have?

Comment: I have a bunch of stuff, ya know... I'm making a quiz and I want the answers to be displayed like in a scoreboard, so I have a pb for answers and for points (about 14 pictureboxes) and I want to animate them using timer, but I want to decide which picturebox the timer tick event should affect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write a little helper class to keep track of the timer and the picture box.  It could look like this:

```
    class Animator : IDisposable {
        private Timer timer;
        private PictureBox pbox;
        private int maxSize;
        public Animator(PictureBox box, int size) {
            pbox = box;
            maxSize = size;
            timer = new Timer() { Interval = 45, Enabled = true };
            timer.Tick += animate;
        }
        private void animate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
             if (pbox.IsDisposed || pbox.Width >= maxSize) Dispose();
             else pbox.Width += Math.Min(2, maxSize - pbox.Width);
        }
        public void Dispose() { timer.Dispose();  }
    }
```

Now you can create as many as you want with a simple statement in your Form class:

```
   new Animator(pictureBox1, 50);
```